# how can i set timeout for page loading in Mink with Selenium 2 driver?

Tags: php, functional-testing, mink

My application uses Mink with Selenium 2 driver. when i try to load the page with some resources that are loading slow (or not loading at all) the application waits infinitely until everything is loaded.

for i have several hundreds of iterations in my application - you can imagine how long the script is executed.

question: is there any possibility to set a timeout for page to load? and throw some exception if the page is not loaded during that period?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://alex-panshin.me/blog/how-to-set-pageload-timeout-for-selenium-with-behat/) you can do it like that:

```
$driver->setTimeouts(['page load' => 10000]);
```

This timeout is in milliseconds.

Answer (score -1):

To set timeout for loading for page in **selenium ide** follow these steps:

**1.** Open selenium ide.

**2.** Click on option menu.

**3.** In general tab change defult timeout value for recorded command.

![Selenium ide image after click on option menu][1]

In **selenium 2** use this function

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```

**Try this**

```
 private $timeout = 60000;


public function reload()
    {
        $this->browser
            ->refresh()
            ->waitForPageToLoad($this->timeout)
        ;
    }
  [1]: h
```

ttp://i.stack.imgur.com/0NKoC.png

Comment: thanks, Naveen! but i'm not talking about Selenium IDE. i'm using Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: I hope this time you got your answer.

Comment: thanks again! but i use Behat/Mink - which means i use PHP and Mink's native PHP binding for Selenium. unfortunately, i cannot do anytning until the page is fully loaded.

Comment: just once look on this link "https://github.com/Behat/MinkSeleniumDriver/blob/master/src/Behat/Mink/Driver/SeleniumDriver.php"

Comment: you mean the $timeout parameter, right? look here (Selenium 2 Driver) https://github.com/Behat/MinkSelenium2Driver/blob/master/src/Behat/Mink/Driver/Selenium2Driver.php - there is no such parameter no more. that is the problem!

Answer (score -1):

please use below three functions in your Featurecontext.php

```
public function spin($lambda, $retries,$sleep)  {
do {
$result = $lambda($this);
} while (!$result && --$retries && sleep($sleep) !== false);


}
public function find($type, $locator, $retries = 20, $sleep = 1) {
return $this->spin(function($context) use ($type,$locator) {

$page = $context->getSession()->getPage();
if ($el = $page->find($type, $locator)) {
    if ($el->isVisible()) {
        return $el->isVisible();
    }
}
return null;
}, $retries, $sleep);
```

}

```
/**
* Wait for a element till timeout completes
*
*  @Then /^(?:|I )wait for "(?P<element>[^"]*)" element$/
*/
public function iWaitForSecondsForFieldToBeVisible($seconds,$element) {

  //$this->iWaitSecondsForElement( $this->timeoutDuration, $element);
$this->find('xpath',$element);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The [Behat documentation](http://docs.behat.org/cookbook/using_spin_functions.html) suggests to use a custom spin() function inside your context.

The following spin() function example is taken from the behat documentation:

```
public function spin ($lambda, $wait = 60)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < $wait; $i++)
    {
        try {
            if ($lambda($this)) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // do nothing
        }

        sleep(1);
    }

    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();

    throw new Exception(
        "Timeout thrown by " . $backtrace[1]['class'] . "::" . $backtrace[1]['function'] . "()\n" .
        $backtrace[1]['file'] . ", line " . $backtrace[1]['line']
    );
}
```

Unfortunately I don't have a working example how to integrate this into your context.

Comment: thank you, t3node :) but the problem is here: $this->session = new \Behat\Mink\Session($driver);
$this->session->start();
$this->session->visit('some URL') - when the visit is executed - you cannot do anything until page is loaded. and the decision you suggest can be applied after the page is loaded. some hard pages (on weak servers) can load for very long time. i would like to control that.

Comment: @Axarsu I know this is almost 6 years ago, but how did you resolve this issue?